# When local variable stack gets created?

Tags: java, jvm, this, bytecode, super

I am learning internals of jvm and i read [this](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html) article. While reading i got one doubt i.e
**When local variable stack get created ?** If **local variable stack** created at run time will **this**, **super** keywords point real objects Or if **local variable stack** is created at compile time, how this, super keywords internally works?

Comment: Local variable are virtually created when you virtually call a method.  However it's all virtual which can mean the method and even the local variables might not exist after the code has been optimised, it's entirely notional.

Comment: @RealSkeptic `this` is always the 0-th variable on the stack in byte code. `super` on the other hand is just `this` which has been cast to use method of the parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When local variable stack get created ?

The `javac` allocates local variables to a stack in byte code.  This allocation is notional and the actual allocation in a real machine could be very different.

After the `JIT` has optimised the code,the local variables and the method itself could be inlined in which case, nothing happens in an ideal situation.

> If local variable stack created at run time will this, super keywords point real objects

There is no `super` at runtime.  There is only the current objects available such as the one which represents `this` and the methods you can call on them. When you use `super` you are referring to methods in the parent class rather than the current one.

> Or if local variable stack is created at compile time, how this, super keywords internally works?

`super` changes which methods the compiler chooses to call.  Once this choice has been made, the distinction between `super` and `this` is discarded.